# RegEx to check validate if string has 0 or more numerical values & other items

Tags: c#, regex

I'm very much a beginner at Regular Expressions, so I'm stuck on something that should possibly be fairly simple - or maybe it isn't, I just wouldn't know.  Also apologies for the fact that I will be putting in step-by-step what my thought process was, not sure if it actually helps.

Anyway I want to validate that a value entered by the user conforms to certain standards that I lay out.  These are:
A maximum length of 10
A minimum length of 4
At least 4 letters
A variable minimum of numbers (currently 0)

So theoretically the value of aa1aa2 would pass.

Initially I started with the following, it validated 4 lower case or 4 upper case.

```
[a-z]{4}|[A-Z]{4}$
```

But this didn't allow for either/or, which lead me to update it

```
([a-z]|[A-Z]){4}$
```

To validate whether it contained the necessary minimum of numbers I changed it to:

```
(([a-z]|[A-Z]){4})([0-9]{0})$
```

I could bore people by putting in different attempts that worked / failed under certain scenarios, but basically I started to notice that it only validated instances where there were 4 letters and a number, I eventually (with help from a colleague) came up with this:

```
^(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]{4}$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{4,10}$)
```

This almost works as I'd want it.  It will validate the length of the string, and whether there are upper / lower cases, but will only work if I include a number.  Any attempts I've made to strip out the 0-0 in the second half (before {4,10}) and adding {0} have not been successful.  Basically without a number it won't work!

How can I modify the final snippet so that I can set a clause where there are potentially 0 numbers?

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion: even if you create a regex that can validate those four conditions, and I'm not sure you can, it will be totally impossible for anyone reading your code to understand its intent. I recommend splitting the validation into steps, and using separate, much-simpler expressions to validate each step.

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/ is a pretty cool site to learn regex and test it out

Answer (score 3):

In C# regex engine (as in PCRE), you can use `\p{L}` to match any lower/upper case Unicode letter. Restrictions are set with the help of look-aheads. Anchors (`^` and `$`) are used to check whole string/line.

Here is a regex that will check your conditions. Right now, it requires exactly 1 digit to be entered:

```
^(?=.*\p{L}.*\p{L}.*\p{L}.*\p{L}.*$)(?=.*\d.*$).{4,10}$
```

Explanation:

- `^` - String/Line start
- `(?=.*\p{L}.*\p{L}.*\p{L}.*\p{L}.*$)` - Positive look-ahead to require at least 4 Unicode letters that may be non-consecutive.
- `(?=.*\d.*$)` - Positive look-ahead to require at least 1 digit
- `.{4,10}` - Any characters, 4 to 10 occurrences
- `$` - String/line end

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3D.*%5Cp%7BL%7D.*%5Cp%7BL%7D.*%5Cp%7BL%7D.*%5Cp%7BL%7D.*%24)(%3F%3D.*%5Cd.*%24).%7B4%2C10%7D%24&i=aa1aa2) on [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester).

Answer (score 0):

As Dan suggested, I also very much prefer a more readable approach:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var input = "testtest";
     var numDigits = 2;

     bool valid = input.Length > 3
                  && input.Length < 11
                  && input.Where(char.IsLetter).Count() > 3
                  && input.Where(char.IsDigit).Count() > numDigits;
 }
```

Using this approach, you could segment the validation, and provide a more helpful response to the user : `input must be at least 4 letters` etc